# Upload a image to Google Cloud Storage using Rest end point via API-KEY

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, storage

I am new to Google Cloud. I want to upload an image to my Bucket.
I did it successfully from the GCP Console and GCP Shell. However, I am unable to do it using REST Endpoint using API-KEY.
Here is my URL.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/[MY_BUCKET]/o?uploadType=media&name=myhero&key=[MY_API-KEY]
```

I am getting the following message

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "required",
                "message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to [MY_BUCKET]/myhero.",
                "locationType": "header",
                "location": "Authorization"
            }
        ],
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to [MY_BUCKET]/myhero."
    }
}
```

This is because the bucket currently does not allow any way to allow users with the API-KEY even though the API-KEY allows the user of this key to upload an object to the bucket.

What should I do 
1) if I want to go with the API-key way.
2) if I want to go with service-account way. What is the best way to generate Authorisation token? I have come till this point

```
{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}.
{
"iss":"761326798069-r5mljlln1rd4lrbhg75efgigp36m78j5@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
"scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction",
"aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
"exp":1328554385,
"iat":1328550785
}.
```

But I am unable to generate {Base64url encoded signature} as I am unable to figure out the private and public keys...

Answer (score 0):

You are getting “anonymous caller” because you are not properly authenticated. You can authenticate using a bearer token instead of the API-KEY.

You can run the following script:

```
BUCKET=<BUCKET_NAME>
OBJECT=<OBJECT>
TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)
 curl "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/$BUCKET/o?uploadType=media&name=$OBJECT" -H"Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H'Content-Type: image/jpg'  --data-binary @$OBJECT
```